# I can't seem to add or remove from database and update the datagrid based on the database. Why?

Tags: c#, database, datagrid, insert, sql-delete

I am working on a library database where you can add and remove book from the database.

**Button 1 problem**
When I press the button1(add record to database and reload database in datagrid) it works on the first click of button1 and when I change what text in the textboxes(title, author, stock) to add to the database and click the button again, it doesn't change what is being added to the database.
example 
textbox1.text(title)= "Harry potter" textbox2.text(author)="jk" textbox3.text(stock)="3"
button1(add) pressed.  Works okay on the first click of button1.  When I change the value of the textbox1-3
example
textbox1.text(title)= "alchemist" textbox2.text(author)="paollo cuello" textbox3.text(stock)="5"
it still record "Harry potter", "jk",  and "3".

**Button2 problem**
When I press button 2(remove record in database and reload database in datagrid) it works on the first click but doesn't really show on the datagrid.
example. 
datagrid shows values
  title        author   stock
  "harrypotter"   "jk"     3 and
  "alchemist"     "pc"     4

textbox1.text(title)= "harrypotter" textbox2.text(author)="jk" textbox3.text(stock)="3"
button2(remove and reload datagrid) is pressed.
result = datagrid doesnt load the new records but harry potter record was deleted in the database
When I try to delete another record.
example.
  title        author stock
  harrypotter   jk     3
  alchemist     pc     4

notice that "harrypotter" still there because reload didnt work.
textbox1.text(title)= "alchemst" textbox2.text(author)="pc" textbox3.text(stock)="4"
button2(remove and reload datagrid) is pressed.
It doesn't work.  I bet it was trying to delete the "harrypotter record still"

Why?

```
public partial class AddBook : Form
{
    String title = "", author = "";
    bool hasValue1 = false, hasValue2 = false, hasValue3 = false;
    string holder = "";
    int stock = 0;

    OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Jc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\itswn\Library System\Library System\LibrarySystemDatabase.accdb;Persist Security Info=True");
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataReader reader;

    public AddBook()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AddBook_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Title", "Title");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Author", "Author");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Stock", "Stock");
        connect.Open();
        loaddataBook();
    }


    private void loaddataBook()
    {

        int i = 0;
        try
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT Title, Author, Stock FROM Book";
            command.Connection = connect;
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Title"].Value = reader[0].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Author"].Value = reader[1].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Stock"].Value = reader[2].ToString();
                    i++;
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            connect.Close();

        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            connect.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        connect.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        title = textBox1.Text.ToLower();
        author = textBox2.Text.ToLower();
        stock = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);

        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            hasValue1 = true;
        }
        if (textBox2.Text != "")
        {
            hasValue2 = true;
        }
        if (textBox3.Text != "")
        {
            hasValue3 = true;
        }
        if (int.Parse(textBox3.Text) >= 0 || textBox3.Text == "")
        {
            if (hasValue1 && hasValue2 && hasValue3)
            {

                try
                {
                    connect.Open();
                    command.Connection = connect;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", author);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stock", stock);
                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Book](Title, Author, Stock) VALUES(@title, @author, @stock)";
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    loaddataBook();
                    connect.Close();
                }
                catch (OleDbException ex)
                {
                    connect.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
                connect.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                label4.Text = "required";
                label5.Text = "required";
                label6.Text = "required";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Stock should not be less than 0", "Keep in mind");
        }

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        title = textBox1.Text.ToLower();
        author = textBox2.Text.ToLower();
        textBox3.Clear(); 
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            hasValue1 = true;
        }
        if (textBox2.Text != "")
        {
            hasValue2 = true;
        }

        if (hasValue1 && hasValue2)
        { 

                try
                {
                    connect.Open();
                    command.Connection = connect;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", author);
                    command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM [Book] WHERE Title = @title AND Author = @author";
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    loaddataBook();
                    connect.Close();
                }
                catch (OleDbException ex)
                {
                    connect.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                label4.Text = "required";
                label5.Text = "required";
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the update function of the sql not insert function for example

```
update [tablename]
set [Book] = [valueof book] , [author ] = [valueofauthor] , so on~~
where statement  you want to update~~~~
```

example where title = harrypotter.

this is for button1.

Comment: But i have no intentions of updating any record.  The update im referring to is the datagrid which holds the database.